# Fermat's Little Theorem: $r \equiv s \pmod {p-1} \implies a^r \equiv a^s \pmod p$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

An implication of Fermat's Little Theorem is the following:

If $p$ is prime, and $a$ is not a multiple of $p$, then
$$r \equiv s \pmod {p-1} \implies a^r \equiv a^s \pmod p.$$

I need this implication to prove the verification of the Elgamal signature, but I honestly do not see how to derive from Fermat's Little Theorem to this implication and I could not find any proof of this.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You can use the following [properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic#Properties) to show that: (1) if $a_1 \equiv b_1 \pmod{p}$ and $a_2 \equiv b_2 \pmod{p}$ then $a_1\, a_2 \equiv b_1\, b_2 \pmod{p}$, and (2) if $k\,a \equiv k\,b \pmod{p}$ and $k$ is coprime with $p$, then $a \equiv b \pmod{p}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assume without loss of generality that $r\geq s$, so $r=s+k(p-1)$ for some $k\geq 0$. Then $a^r=a^sa^{k(p-1)}$. Can you see how to get from here to what you want?

Comment: Yes, because $a^{k(p-1)}= a^{(p-1)^k} = 1^k = 1$. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is a more  universal Theorem to get it.
The Theorem lies in 《elementary number thoery 6th》  **Theorem 9.2**.
It can be used to prove the verification of the Elgamal signature  and DSA.
DSA is a much more popular variant of  the Elgamal signature.

**Theorem 9.2** If $a$ and $n$ are relative prime integers with $n>0$,then $a^i \equiv a^j \pmod n$,where i and j are nonnegative integers, if and only if $i \equiv j \pmod {ord_n^a}$

Specially, when $p$ is a prime integer, ${ord_p^a}=\varphi(p)=p-1$ , so we get the result:
**Corollary** If $a$ and $p$ are relative prime integers, and $p$ is a prime integer,then $a^i \equiv a^j \pmod p$,where i and j are nonnegative integers, if and only if $i \equiv j \pmod {p-1}$

hence:

$$i \equiv j \pmod {p-1} \Leftrightarrow a^i \equiv a^j \pmod p.$$

That is the answer.

Comment: Who is the author of the book you reference?

Comment: Kenneth H. Rosen