# Suppose $p$ is prime and $m \gt 0$ and $n \gt 0$ and $m \equiv n \pmod{p-1}$. Prove that $a^m \equiv a^n \pmod{p}$ for all $a$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Suppose $p$ is prime and $m \gt 0$ and $n \gt 0$ and $m \equiv n \pmod{p-1}$. Prove that $a^m \equiv a^n \pmod{p}$ for all $a$.

I know I have to apply Fermat's little theorem to prove this, but I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$a^{m-n}=a^{k(p-1)}\equiv1\pmod p$$

$$\frac{a^m}{a^n}\equiv1\pmod p$$

$$a^m\equiv a^n \pmod p$$

Answer (score 0):

Since $m = k(p-1) + n$ for some $k \in \mathbb Z$, $a^m = (a^k)^{p-1}a^n$, so apply Fermat's little theorem. Maybe you should split into two cases: either $p \mid a$ (trivial), or $p \nmid a$.

EDIT: actually, the same question is asked here: [Fermat's Little Theorem: $r \equiv s \pmod {p-1} \implies a^r \equiv a^s \pmod p$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2814424/fermats-little-theorem-r-equiv-s-pmod-p-1-implies-ar-equiv-as-pmod-p?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

If $a \equiv 0 \pmod{n}$, then [automatically](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic#Properties) $a^m \equiv a^n \pmod{n}$, so let's consider the case when $a \not\equiv 0 \pmod{n}$, i.e., $a$ is not evenly divisible by $p$. Without loss of generality, we can also assume that $m \leq n$.

By using the property that if $a_1 \equiv b_1 \pmod{c}$ and $a_2 \equiv b_2 \pmod{c}$ then $a_1\, a_2 \equiv b_1\, b_2 \pmod{c}$, we can use [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) to multiply any modular arithmetic equation with $a$ on one side and with $a^p$ on the other side.

Since $m \equiv n \pmod{p-1}$, we know that

$$
d = \frac{n-m}{p-1}
$$

is an non-negative integer.

Starting from $a^0 \equiv a^0 \pmod{n}$, we need to create a difference of $n-m$ in the exponent between the LHS and the RHS. Let's multiply the LHS by $a$ and the RHS by $a^p$ for a total of $d$ times (if $d = 0$, do nothing); this should give us the desired difference in exponent. Doing this gives

$$
a^{d} \equiv a^{pd} \pmod{n}\qquad\text{(*)}.
$$

If $d < m$, we need to increase the exponent on both sides. So, for $d \leq m$, if we multiply both sides of this equation by $a^{m - d}$, we get

$$
a^{d}a^{m - d} \equiv a^{pd}a^{m - d} \pmod{n}.
$$

Now, $a^{d}a^{m - d} = a^m$, and $a^{pd}a^{m - d} = a^{p(n-m)/(p-1)}a^{m - (n-m)/(p-1)} = a^{(p-1)(n-m)/(p-1) + m} = a^{n}$, which gives us

$$
a^m \equiv a^n \pmod{n},
$$

as expected. On the other hand, if $d > m$, we would like to divide both sides by $a^{d-m}$ to decrease the exponent. There is a property that if $k\,a \equiv k\,b \pmod{c}$ and $k$ is coprime with $c$, then $a \equiv b \pmod{c}$. Since $a \not\equiv 0 \pmod{p}$, we know that $a$ and $p$ are coprime, so we can decrease the exponent on both sides in (*) by dividing by $a$. Doing this $d-m$ times yields

$$
a^{d}/a^{d-m} \equiv a^{pd}/a^{d-m} \pmod{n},
$$

which after substituting $(n-m)/(p-1)$ for $d$ also gives

$$
a^m \equiv a^n \pmod{n}.
$$